# Babel cannot parse @wordpress packages

Tags: wordpress, babeljs, wordpress-rest-api, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

When I try to use @wordpress/api-fetch, I am getting following errors when compiling:

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@wordpress/hooks/build-module/createCurrentHook.js
> 15:90 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:90) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file.
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@wordpress/i18n/build-module/create-i18n.js
> 196:29 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (196:29) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file.

This is my babel config, with `@wordpress-default` listed under presets.

```
module.exports = {
    'presets': [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: {
                    version: 3,
                    proposals: true
                },
            }
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@wordpress/default'
    ],
};
```

`"@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "^4.8.0",` is listed in the package.json

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Although not fixing the actual issue, loading api-fecth with `wp.apiFetch` solves the problem.